# How to transfer data from variable to redux storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a getPostById method that makes an asynchronous request and returns the post we clicked on. How to create a variable in redux 'postArticle' and write in the data that came from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/$ {id}`?

```
getPostById = async(id: any) => {
    const myResponse = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
    const myJson = await myResponse.json();
    const IWantToRedux = myJson.body
}
```

my actions

```
export const GET_ID = 'GET_ID'

export const getPostById = (changedBody: any) => ({
    type: GET_ID,
    payload: changedBody,
});

const initialState = {
    background: "blue",
    changedBody: 'hello',
}
```

my reducer

```
export function pageReducer(state = initialState, action: any) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ID:
            return {...state, getPostByIdAction: action.payload};
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello there! What have you already tried? You can't do asyncronous actions using only Redux, you need a middleware to do that, I suggest you Redux Thunk https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: Check out [Async Action Creators](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/#async-action-creators). You need to dispatch() actions with the appropriate payload when the request has finished from the fetch. use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).

Comment: @Celso Wellington Hi ! My achievements can be seen in the code. Ofc i`m using middleware and 
 thunk like that: createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)).The question is, I can’t understand the logic of how I can transfer data from variable to redux storage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I get it. You're using middleware, well, since it runs before your Redux action, you must return `dispatch` and then dispatch it, like this:

```
getPostById = async(id: any) => {
    const myResponse = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
    const myJson = await myResponse.json();
    const IWantToRedux = myJson.body
    return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: GET_ID, payload: IWantToRedux});
            }
}
```

I'm considering that this asynchronous action is being triggered in the redux actions (in your component, you must dispatch this action, not the type/payload);
Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: The logic is: the middleware will return the dispatch function after he done all it's work. The dispatch function you'll return must be synchronous, or bugs will happen.

Comment: It still not working for me.. how can I transfer dispatch out of getPostById function? I think I should do dispatch in mapDispatchToProps like this:const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
        getIdAction: (IWantToRedux: any) => dispatch(getId(IWantToRedux))
    };
}

Comment: you can do an asyncrhonous request inside your component, then pass it directly to redux, like this: const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => { return { getIdAction: (IWantToRedux: any) => dispatch({type: GET_ID, payload: IWantToRedux) }; }